# No instance of constructor matches argument list

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I know this question has been asked before and I have attempted the solutions posted but for some reason I still cannot solve the problem I am facing.

I am trying to create an object of a derived class. However, I get an error message saying :

> ```
> Error: no instance of constructor "CALibrary::YieldCurve::YieldCurve"
> matches te argument list argument types are: (std::string,
> std::vector<std::pair<double,double>,double>)
> ```

The parent class is:

```
namespace CALibrary {
  class YieldCurveIF {
  public:
    virtual double getDiscountFactor(double fromDate, double toDate) = 0;
      int getSize() {
        return _curve.size();
      }
      std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> getCurve() {
        return _curve;
      }

      void setParameters(std::string curveName,
                         std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>& curve)
      {
        _curveName = curveName;
        _curve = curve;
      }
  protected:
    std::string                            _curveName;
    std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> _curve;
  };
}
```

The derived class is:

```
namespace CALibrary {
  class YieldCurve : public CALibrary::YieldCurveIF
  {
  public:
    YieldCurve(std::string curveName,
               std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>& curve)
    {           
      setParameters(curveName, curve);
    }
    double getDiscountFactor(double fromDate, double toDate);
    private:
  };
}
```

Here is code where I am trying to creat an object of YieldCurve is:

```
int nPayments = 4;
std::string curveName = "EURCurve"; 
std::vector<std::pair<double, double>, double> yCurve(nPayments);
CALibrary::YieldCurve   _yieldCurve(curveName, yCurve);
```

Comment: Error occurs in line "CALibrary::YieldCurve _yieldCurve(curveName, yCurve);" especially the variable "curveName".

Comment: Have you tried fixing the type of `yCurve` (line 3 of last piece of code)? The third `double` shouldn't be present.

Answer (score 0):

`yCurve` has a nonsense type

```
std::vector<std::pair<double, double>, double>
```

remove the `,double` at the end.

In addition, your code takes `std::vector<std::pair<double, double>>&` when it should be taking `std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> const&` in two places.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply

Comment: Sorry Yakk I am not very good with knowing when to use "const". Can you please explain why should my code be taking "std::vector<std::pair<double,double>> const&" in two places? Thanks

Comment: @Ace Are you modifying something?  If you are not modifying something, directly or indirectly, you should take it by `const&` not by `&`.  Does `setParameters` modify the `vector` it is passed?

Comment: ,Nope, "setParameters" sets the "_curve" in the parent class to "curve" that is passed in the "setParameters" method. Other classes can use the "getDiscountFactor" method to retrieve values from the "_curve". The only reason I have used "&" is because I did not want the compiler to create another copy of "curve" when the "setParameters" method is called. I thought it would be more efficient to just pass by reference.

Comment: @ace `_curve` is not the same variable as `curve`, and you copy the data in the `=`.  So, no, your nope is wrong.